# Adding Vertical Spacing between two views programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I have these views, both are the same, i want to add them programmatically so i want to add constraints programmatically, i've managed to do same using storyboard but i want to use code for this.

[image: this is what i want to create]

i want to add margins to these views so that first one is at the top, next one is below the first one and so,

i've wrote code like this:

```
self.view.addConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: secondView,
        attribute: .Top,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: firstView,
        attribute: .Top,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 0
    ))
```

first view has the constraint in which `toItem` is current view controller and it works, but the second view does not work this way, it just draws it on top of the first view, i want it to be below it, only way i can do this is in `constant: 0` enter the height of the view, which i don't like

any suggestions?

Comment: this helped me i've figured it out, i just realized what second "attribute" attribute was for, now i know :)) thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code you supplied is 99% right but

```
self.view.addConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: secondView,
        attribute: .Top,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: firstView,
        attribute: .Top,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 0
    ))
```

Your attaching the top of secondView to the top of firstView so they would be on top instead you want the top of secondView to the bottom of firstView.

```
self.view.addConstraint(
    NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: secondView,
        attribute: .Top,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: firstView,
        attribute: .Bottom,  <----------
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 0
    ))
```

The constant is the distance.

Comment: yeah i've already figured it out but this is right answer, so when i'll be able to  ill mark this answer as correct one